# clSetKernelArg returns with CL_INVALID_MEM_OBJECT

Tags: opencl

I'm totally green with OpenCL. I'm trying to get a sample on Intel's website to work, but I cannot. [This is the sample](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/jumpstart-tutorial).

I'm getting the error CL_INVALID_MEM_OBJECT when trying to pass an integer argument to clSetKernelArg like so:

```
err = clSetKernelArg(ocl->kernel, 2, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&width);
if (CL_SUCCESS != err)
{
    LogError("Error: Failed to set argument dstMem, returned %s\n", TranslateOpenCLError(err));
    return err;
}
```

The tutorial is supposed to work on an image, and specifically states the arguments should be set as such:

```
err  |= clSetKernelArg(ocl->kernel, 2, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *) &width);
err  |= clSetKernelArg(ocl->kernel, 3, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *) &height);
```

Here is the full function:

```
cl_uint SetKernelArguments(ocl_args_d_t *ocl, cl_uint width, cl_uint height)
{
    cl_int err = CL_SUCCESS;

    err  =  clSetKernelArg(ocl->kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&ocl->srcA);
    if (CL_SUCCESS != err)
    {
        LogError("error: Failed to set argument srcA, returned %s\n", TranslateOpenCLError(err));
        return err;
    }

    err  = clSetKernelArg(ocl->kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&ocl->dstMem);
    if (CL_SUCCESS != err)
    {
        LogError("Error: Failed to set argument dstMem, returned %s\n", TranslateOpenCLError(err));
        return err;
    }

    err = clSetKernelArg(ocl->kernel, 2, sizeof(cl_uint), (void *)&width);
    if (CL_SUCCESS != err)
    {
        LogError("Error: Failed to set argument dstMem, returned %s\n", TranslateOpenCLError(err));
        return err;
    }

    err = clSetKernelArg(ocl->kernel, 3, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&height);
    if (CL_SUCCESS != err)
    {
        LogError("Error: Failed to set argument dstMem, returned %s\n", TranslateOpenCLError(err));
        return err;
    }

    return err;
}
```

**One last note**: changing the size to sizeof(cl_uint) for clSetKernelArg changes the error to CL_INVALID_ARG_SIZE.

In case this isn't enough, I have the source made public on github [here](https://github.com/kwende/SimpleOpenCL/blob/master/EdgeDetectionOnGPU/EdgeDetectionOnGPU.cpp).

Quite certain I followed the instructions well on the tutorial, but I cannot figure out what I may have missed. Thanks for your time.

Comment: can you write kernel function's arguments please such as __global int * a...

Answer (score 2):

I went through your code on github quickly, I think I can give you some advice.

First, call "clCreateBuffer" before you use the "cl_mem" type memory object, in other words, make sure "width" has the type of "cl_mem" before you call

`cl_mem cl_width = clCreateBuffer(context,CL_MEM_READ_WRITE|CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR,
                       sizeof(width), &width,*err);
err = clSetKernelArg(ocl->kernel, 2, sizeof(cl_mem), &cl_width);`

I am not sure whether it will work.

Second, it's depreciated to use "cl_mem" to pass a value such as an "int" or a "char" according to my experience. If I were you, I'll omit the "clCreateBuffer" clause and write the code like:

```
cl_int width = doSomeThingYouWant();
```

`err = clSetKernelArg(ocl->kernel, 2, sizeof(cl_uint), &width);`

Hope it can be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to answer your question briefly.

If we take a look at the definition of clSetKernelArg function:

```
cl_int clSetKernelArg ( cl_kernel kernel,
    cl_uint arg_index,
    size_t arg_size,
    const void *arg_value)
```

you can see, what you need pass to clSetKernelArg is a pointer to your argument, and the size of the argument. Now, your argument is just a normal cl_uint variable. Therefore, we can have the followings:

```
const void *arg_value -> &width
size_t arg_size -> sizeof(width)
```

So, your API call will be like this:

```
err  |= clSetKernelArg(ocl->kernel, 2, sizeof(width), (void *) &width);
err  |= clSetKernelArg(ocl->kernel, 3, sizeof(height), (void *) &height);
```